# mongoose custom validation using 2 fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to use mongoose custom validation to validate if endDate is greater than startDate. How can I access startDate value? When using **this.startDate**, it doesn't work; I get undefined.

```
var a = new Schema({
  startDate: Date,
  endDate: Date
});

var A = mongoose.model('A', a);

A.schema.path('endDate').validate(function (value) {
  return diff(this.startDate, value) >= 0;
}, 'End Date must be greater than Start Date');
```

`diff` is a function that compares two dates.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could try nesting your date stamps in a parent object and then validate the parent. For example something like:

```
//create a simple object defining your dates
var dateStampSchema = {
  startDate: {type:Date},
  endDate: {type:Date}
};

//validation function
function checkDates(value) {
   return value.endDate < value.startDate; 
}

//now pass in the dateStampSchema object as the type for a schema field
var schema = new Schema({
   dateInfo: {type:dateStampSchema, validate:checkDates}
});
```

Answer (score 106):

You can do that using Mongoose `'validate'` [middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) so that you have access to all fields:

```
ASchema.pre('validate', function(next) {
    if (this.startDate > this.endDate) {
        next(new Error('End Date must be greater than Start Date'));
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Note that you must wrap your validation error message in a JavaScript `Error` object when calling `next` to report a validation failure.

Comment: I have in my controller in nodejs 
    exports.create = function (req, res, next) {
       var a = new A(req.body);
       // I added your code here but it does'nt work
       newEvent.save(function(err) {
          if (err) {
            return res.json(400, err);
          }
          return res.json({message:'success'});
    });
@JohnnyHK : Where am I supposed to add your code example
Thnks

Comment: This is a much cleaner approach than the accepted answer, thanks @JohnnyHK

Comment: I tried it but the error is not returned to the `entity.save()` callback.

Comment: @AdrienG Go ahead and post a new question with the full details if you still need help.

Comment: Maybe it's my fault but I found another way to do it: I used instead `this.invalidate('myField', 'my error message.', this.myField);` so it's ok thanks :)

Comment: In case the error is not showing up for anyone, make sure to add `new` before `Error` when creating the error object. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error).

Comment: @Austen The `new` is optional in the node.js implementation of the `Error` constructor, so either way is fine.

Comment: Be aware `pre('validate',...` middleware does not execute for `findOneAndUpdate()`  https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/964

Answer (score 39):

An an alternative to the accepted answer for the original question is:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// schema definition
var ASchema = new Schema({
  startDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },
  endDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    validate: [dateValidator, 'Start Date must be less than End Date']
  }
});

// function that validate the startDate and endDate
function dateValidator(value) {
  // `this` is the mongoose document
  return this.startDate <= value;
}
```

Comment: Great! And if you require one of two fields you can create the validation on a required field, but check what you need via `this`.

Comment: this option fails when use .findOneAndUpdate with runValidators options. this has wrong context so .startDate will not be available :(

Comment: Same problem when using findByIdAndUpdate with runValidators:true as Denis mentioned

Comment: @Denis For me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70087952/4222504) solution resolved the issue that you mentioned.
Also, check out my comment under the linked answer. Hope this help!

Answer (score 32):

I wanted to expand upon the solid answer from @JohnnyHK (thank you) by tapping into this.invalidate:

```
Schema.pre('validate', function (next) {
  if (this.startDate > this.endDate) {
    this.invalidate('startDate', 'Start date must be less than end date.', this.startDate);
  }

  next();
});
```

This keeps all of the validation errors inside of a mongoose.Error.ValidationError error. Helps to keep error handlers standardized. Hope this helps.

Comment: Just what I needed! Now I just need to figure out why mongoose isn't hitting the validate hook before saving...

Comment: Nix the above, this solution is perfect. It should be the accepted. Thanks @kognizant !!!

Answer (score 6):

Using 'this' within the validator works for me - in this case when checking the uniqueness of email address I need to access the id of the current object so that I can exclude it from the count:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: String,
  name: { type: String, required: true},
  email: {
    type: String,
    index: {
      unique: true, dropDups: true
    },
    validate: [
      { validator: validator.isEmail, msg: 'invalid email address'},
      { validator: isEmailUnique, msg: 'Email already exists'}
    ]},
  facebookId: String,
  googleId: String,
  admin: Boolean
});

function isEmailUnique(value, done) {
  if (value) {
    mongoose.models['users'].count({ _id: {'$ne': this._id }, email: value }, function (err, count) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      // If `count` is greater than zero, "invalidate"
      done(!count);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I used (thanks to @shakinfree for the hint) :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// schema definition
var ASchema = new Schema({
  dateSchema : {
                type:{
                    startDate:{type:Date, required: true}, 
                    endDate:{type:Date, required: true}
                }, 
                required: true, 
                validate: [dateValidator, 'Start Date must be less than End Date']
            }
});

// function that validate the startDate and endDate
function dateValidator (value) {
    return value.startDate <= value.endDate;
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('A', ASchema);
```

Comment: Be carefully with this aproach because there is bug in 4.01 https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2814