# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate and runValidators not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

I am having issues trying to get the 'runValidators' option to work. My user schema has an email field that has required set to true but each time a new user gets added to the database (using the 'upsert' option) and the email field is empty it does not complain:

```
 var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   facebookId: {type: Number, required: true},
   activated: {type: Boolean, required: true, default: false},
   email: {type: String, required: true}
});
```

`findOneAndUpdate` code:

```
model.user.user.findOneAndUpdate(
      {facebookId: request.params.facebookId},
      {
          $setOnInsert: {
              facebookId: request.params.facebookId,
              email: request.payload.email,
          }
      },
      {upsert: true, 
       new: true, 
       runValidators: true, 
       setDefaultsOnInsert: true
      }, function (err, user) {
          if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              return reply(boom.badRequest(authError));
          }
          return reply(user);
      });
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, I just followed the docs: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

In the docs is says the following:

> Note that in mongoose 4.x, update validators only run on $set and $unset operations. For instance, the below update will succeed, regardless of the value of number.

I replaced the $setOnInsert with $set but had the same result.

Comment: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3124

Answer (score 10):

> required validators only fail when you try to explicitly $unset the key.

This makes no sense to me but it's what the docs say.

Comment: when I use $unset, key then it asked me for validation. but still, I am not getting to update the collection.

Comment: Is there a way to enforce the required validation if the field is unset?

Answer (score 7):

use this plugin:
[mongoose-unique-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-validator)

When using methods like `findOneAndUpdate` you will need to pass this configuration object:

{ runValidators: true, context: 'query' }

ie.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { email: 'old-email@example.com' },
  { email: 'new-email@example.com' },
  { runValidators: true, context: 'query' },
  function(err) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for nested fields using validation

Answer (score 4):

In mongoose do same thing in two step.

1. Find the result using `findOne()` method.
2. Add fields and save document using `Model.save()`.

This will update your document.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the issue by adding a pre hook for findOneAndUpdate():

```
ExampleSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function (next) {
    this.options.runValidators = true
    next()
})
```

Then when I am using findOneAndUpdate the validation is working.

Answer (score 1):

I created a plugin to validate required model properties before doing update operations in mongoose.

**Plugin code here**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var _ = require('lodash');
var s = require('underscore.string');

function validateExtra(schema, options){
    schema.methods.validateRequired = function(){
        var deferred = Promise.defer();
        var self = this;
        try {
            _.forEach(this.schema.paths, function (val, key) {
                if (val.isRequired && _.isUndefined(self[key])) {
                    throw new Error(s.humanize(key) + ' is not set and is required');
                }
            });
            deferred.resolve();
        } catch (err){
            deferred.reject(err);
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}

module.exports = validateExtra;
```

Must be called explicitly as a method from the model, so I recommend chaining it a `.then` chain prior to the update call.

**Plugin in use here**

```
fuelOrderModel(postVars.fuelOrder).validateRequired()
    .then(function(){
        return fuelOrderModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id: postVars.fuelOrder.fuelOrderId}, 
           postVars.fuelOrder, {runValidators: true, upsert: true, 
           setDefaultsOnInsert: true, new: true})
                .then(function(doc) {
                    res.json({fuelOrderId: postVars.fuelOrder.fuelOrderId});
                });
    }, function(err){
            global.saveError(err, 'server', req.user);
            res.status(500).json(err);
    });
```

Comment: The above solution check for both update and insert new one.
But the validatedRequired should only checked on the create case rather than the updated case which is not necessary to have all the required key.

Comment: @AlanLee sure, so remove the `upsert: true` and then it won't do inserts.  How about an upvote for a working solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate with findOneAndUpdate you can not get current document but you can get this keywords's contents and in this keywords's content have "op" property so solution is this :

Note : does not matter if you use context or not. Also, don't forget to send data include both "price" and "priceDiscount" in findOneAndUpdate body.

```
validate: {
        validator: function (value) {
          if (this.op === 'findOneAndUpdate') {
            console.log(this.getUpdate().$set.priceDiscount);
            console.log(this.getUpdate().$set.price);
            return (
              this.getUpdate().$set.priceDiscount < this.getUpdate().$set.price
            );
          }
          return value < this.price;
        },
        message: 'Discount price ({VALUE}) should be below regular price',
      }
```

Comment: You mention that it does not matter if you use context, but this only worked for me when I used `context: 'query'` in the options.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this behavior is that mongoose assumes you are just going to **update** the document, not **insert** one. The only possibility of having an invalid model with upsert is therefore to perform an `$unset`. In other words, `findOneAndUpdate` would be appropriate for a `PATCH` endpoint.
If you want to validate the model on insert, and be able to perform a update on this endpoint too (it would be a `PUT` endpoint) you should use `replaceOne`