# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate: How to runValidators on just the updated fields and not all fields?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

This is not a duplicate of [Mongoose findOneAndUpdate and runValidators not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101984/mongoose-findoneandupdate-and-runvalidators-not-working)
or [runValidators option not working on findByIDAndUpdate or findOneAndUpdate using mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53724348/runvalidators-option-not-working-on-findbyidandupdate-or-findoneandupdate-using)

I am using the Mongoose ODM for Node.js
When I run the following code with the option `{ runValidators: true }` on the last line I get an error because it is attempting to validate an email address as well (not provided in the update).  If I remove `{ run Validators: true }` then the code runs fine however no validation is made on my updated fields.  How do I get Mongoose to run validation on **just** the fields I am providing to update, and not on all the fields in a database entry?

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const User = mongoose.model("User", {
    name: {
        type:    String
    },
    email: {
        type:  String
    }
}

const update = {
    name:  "Jessica"
}

User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, { new: true, runValidators: true })
```

The error that is given when `{ runValidators: true }` is set is: `TypeError: Cannot read property '_update' of undefined`

Comment: Because `runValidators` is only available for `update()`, `updateOne()`, `updateMany()`, and `findOneAndUpdate()` and probably not on **`findByIdAndUpdate()`** [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#validation)

Comment: `runValidators` **is** an available option for `findByIdAndUpdate()`.  You can see here, third bullet point under the **Options** subheader. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate

Comment: Yeah! that makes sense because it triggers `findOneAndUpdate()`. Didn't find that in main docs.