# MongoDB: bulk create or update

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have an array of data that I want to insert in my database:

```
[
  {
    "id":"816307",
    "email": "john.doe@test.com",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
  },
  {
    "id":"391650",
    "email": "mary@williams",
    "firstName": "Mary",
    "lastName": "Williams"
  },
  {
    "id":"183751",
    "email": "paul.smith@test.com",
    "firstName": "Paul",
    "lastName": "Smith"
  },
]
```

I know that I can use the `.create` method from mongoose to insert all the data.

However, in the data, I need to be able to have a combination of new values and existing values. For example, if a user with id `816307` (John Doe) already exists but have a different email it should update the value and at the same time if a user with id `391650` (Mary Williams) does not exist it should create it.

The `id` field cannot be updated.

It seems like the best method to use is currently `updateMany` and to use the `upsert` option to insert new elements at the same time [.updateMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/).

But, how to do to reference the `id`? I cannot use `$eq` and hardcode anything here, I would like that the document automatically finds the proper item by its `id` and update it if it exists, otherwise, create it.

Answer (score 0):

Since each object has it's own filter & update, then you might not be able to do it using `.updateMany()`, instead you can use MongoDB's [.bulkWrite()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/index.html), with which you could do things in one DB call, internally MongoDB would do multiple write ops.

**Try below code :**

```
let input = [
  {
    id: "816307",
    email: "john.doe@test.com",
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
  },
  {
    id: "391650",
    email: "mary@williams",
    firstName: "Mary",
    lastName: "Williams",
  },
  {
    id: "183751",
    email: "paul.smith@test.com",
    firstName: "Paul",
    lastName: "Smith",
  },
];

let bulkArr = [];
input.forEach((each) => {
  bulkArr.push({
    updateOne: {
      filter: each.id,
      update: {
        $set: {
          email: each.email,
          firstName: each.firstName,
          lastName: each.lastName,
        },
      },
      upsert: true,
    },
  });
});

db.collection.bulkWrite(bulkArr)
```

Comment: How should I do to validate the data? I added `runValidators: true` after `upsert: true`, but it doesn't work

Comment: @Raphael : What are you trying to validate ?

Comment: All the entered data

Comment: @Raphael : Does this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31101984/mongoose-findoneandupdate-and-runvalidators-not-working) help you ?