# Mongoose - findByIdAndUpdate runValidators based on other properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to update a model with the following query:

```js
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { min_age: 18, max_age: 24 }, { new: true, runValidators: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true })
```

The thing is that I need to validate that those values aren't opposed to each other like the following query

```js
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { min_age: 24, max_age: 18 }, { new: true, runValidators: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true })
```

the schema I built so far is this one:

```js
let ageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    min_age: {
        type: Number,
        min: 18,
        max: 80,
        required: true,
        validate: {
            validator: function(value) { 
                return this.max_age >= value 
            },
            message: 'min_age has to be lower than or equal to max_age'
        }
    },
    max_age: {
        type: Number,
        min: 18,
        max: 80,
        required: true,
        validate: {
            validator: function(value) { 
                return this.min_age <= value 
            },
            message: 'max_age has to be greater than or equal to min_age'
        }
    }
})
```

The validation works for creating the model, but unfortunately, it doesn't work for updating the data.

When I'm **creating** the model, the `this` keyword refers to the model, which gives me access to other properties on this model.

When I'm **updating** the model, the `this` keyword refers to global, which doesn't give me access to other properties on this model.

Is there any practical way to validate those properties based on other properties during an update?

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't checked this yet, but did you try using an arrow function in the validator?

Comment: When I'm using arrow function the `this` keyword is referring to an empty object `{}`

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70087952/4222504)?
Try to replace findOneAndUpdate with findByIdAndUpdate, maybe will work

Comment: i ran into the same issue and did not find a solution