# Validating fields that depend on each other in Keystone.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose, keystonejs

I'm trying to do validation when saving an item. Here's my pared-down model:

```
Sample.add({
    isPublished: { type: Types.Boolean, default: false },
    thumbnailImage: { type: Types.CloudinaryImage, folder: 'samples/thumbnails' },
});

Sample.schema.pre('validate', function(next) {
    if (this.isPublished && !(_.isEmpty(this.thumbnailImage.image))) {
        next('Thumbnail Image is required when publishing a sample');
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
});
```

I want to raise an error if a `Sample` model has `isPublished` set to `true` but a `thumbnailImage` hasn't been set. When I `console.log()` the values, I see `true` and `false` respectively, but no validation error is raised in Keystone Admin.

I've looked through the sample applications on Github for Keystone, and the Mongoose docs have plenty of examples, but I haven't seen any that handle multiple document paths.

The example at: [mongoose custom validation using 2 fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760253/mongoose-custom-validation-using-2-fields) (currently with 12 upvotes) isn't working for me either.

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Mongoose 3.8.35.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't be `!` negating the second part of your validation condition, as you're currently flagging a validation error when it's *not* empty.

So change it to:

```
Sample.schema.pre('validate', function(next) {
    if (this.isPublished && _.isEmpty(this.thumbnailImage.image)) {
        next(Error('Thumbnail Image is required when publishing a sample'));
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Note that you also need to wrap your error string in an [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) object when calling `next` to report a validation failure.

Comment: OFFS. Thanks for pointing that out. The message I'm getting now is: `TypeError: string is not a function`. I'm assuming I need to pass a callback function?

Comment: Yeppers. I was just about to post the same thing. Thank you so much for the help. Obviously, I need more coffee.