# Mongoose custom validation of several fields on update

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

First of all, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760253/mongoose-custom-validation-using-2-fields) doesn't help.

Let's say, we have a User model:

```js
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    active: { type: Boolean },
    avatar: { type: String }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', schema);
```

When we update it (set an avatar):

```js
// This should pass validation
User.update({ _id: id }, { $set: { avatar: 'user1.png' } });
```

We want to validate it based on current (or changed) `active` attribute value.

#### Case #1

- `active` is `false`
- we **should not** be able to set avatar - it **should not pass** the validation

#### Case #2

- `active` is `true`
- we **should** be able to set avatar - it **should pass** the validation

#### Ideas

1. Use a custom validator

```js
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    active: { type: Boolean },
    avatar: { type: String, validate: [validateAvatar, 'User is not active'] }
});

function validateAvatar (value) {
    console.log(value); // user.avatar
    console.log(this.active); // undefined
}
```

So this will not work as we don't have an access to `active` field.

2. Use pre "validate" hook

```js
schema.pre('validate', function (next) {
    // this will never be called
});
```

This hook doesn't work with `update` method.

3. Use pre "update" hook

```js
schema.pre('update', function (next) {
    console.log(this.active); // undefined
});
```

This will not work for us as it doesn't have an access to model fields.

4. Use post "update" hook

```js
schema.post('update', function (next) {
    console.log(this.active); // false
});
```

This one works, but in terms of validation is not quite good choice, as the function is being called only when model was already saved.

#### Question

So is there a way to validate the model based on several fields (both saved in DB and new ones) before saving it, while using `model.update()` method?

As a summary:

1. Initial user object

```js
{ active: false, avatar: null }
```

2. Update

```js
User.update({ _id: id }, { $set: { avatar: 'user1.png' } });
```

3. Validation should have an access to

```js
{ active: false, avatar: 'user1.png' }
```

4. If validation fails, changes should not be passed to DB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to limitation of working with `update()` I've decided to solve the problem this way:

- Use custom validators (idea #1 mentioned in the question)
- Don't use `update()`

So instead of

```
User.update({ _id: id }, { $set: { avatar: 'user1.png' } });
```

I use

```
User.findOne({ _id: id })
    .then((user) => {
        user.avatar = 'user1.png';
        user.save();
    });
```

In this case custom validators work as expected.

P.S. I choose this answer as a correct one for me, but I will give bounty to the most relevant answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the context option specified in the [mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html).

> **The context option**
>
> The context option lets you set the value of this in update validators
>   to the underlying query.

---

So in your code you can define your `validator` on the path like this:

```
function validateAvatar (value) {
    // When running update validators with the `context` option set to
    // 'query', `this` refers to the query object.
    return this.getUpdate().$set.active;
}

schema.path('avatar').validate(validateAvatar, 'User is not active');
```

And while updating you need to enter two options `runValidators` and `context`. So your update query becomes:

```
var opts = { runValidators: true, context: 'query' };
user.update({ _id: id }, { $set: { avatar: 'user1.png' }, opts });
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but it doesn't work. `this.getUpdate().$set` is an update query object, which in this case is `{ avatar: 'user1.png' }`. So it still doesn't have current `active` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try giving active a default value so it would not be undefined in mongodb.

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
active: { type: Boolean, 'default': false },
avatar: { type: String,
          trim: true,
          'default': '',
          validate: [validateAvatar, 'User is not active']
}});

function validateAvatar (value) {
    console.log(value); // user.avatar
    console.log(this.active); // undefined
}
```

When creating do you set the user in this way

```
  var User = mongoose.model('User');
  var user_1 = new User({ active: false, avatar: ''});
  user_1.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send({message: 'err'});
            }               
            res.json(user_1);                
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with pre "save" hook. I used it before and can get the value in "this".

```
schema.pre('save', function (next) {
    console.log(this.active);
});
```

Hope this work with you too !

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an [asynchronous custom validator](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#async-custom-validators) for that:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  active: { type: Boolean },
  avatar: {
    type     : String,
    validate : {
      validator : validateAvatar,
      message   : 'User is not active'
    }
  }
});

function validateAvatar(v, cb) {
  this.model.findOne({ _id : this.getQuery()._id }).then(user => {
    if (user && ! user.active) {
      return cb(false);
    } else {
      cb();
    }
  });
}
```

(and pass the `runValidators` and `context` options to `update()`, as suggested in the answer from Naeem).

However, this will require an extra query for each update, which isn't ideal.

As an alternative, you could also consider using something like this (if the constraint of not being able to update inactive users is more important than actually validating for it):

```
user.update({ _id : id, active : true }, { ... }, ...);
```

Comment: "Both update statements are exactly the same" - Please take a look at `active` attribute described in both of cases. It's different, that's the main thing there.

Comment: @Leestex but as you may have noticed, your question is confusing because of that.

Comment: I've updated that part of question, hope it isn't such confusing right now

Comment: When I am creating a record it says getQuery() is not a function

Comment: @AliAbbas I think `getQuery()` is only available in update validators. But you should probably create a new question if you can't solve your problem.