# What is the right syntax to make required field depend on another field/function in Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I'm trying to make fields required depending on value in current Mongoose object. 
How can I make customerInfo required depend on the value in status in below?

this reference is not working in that function.

Ideally would prefer to declare the function outside the schema definition too but couldn't get it to work. I also couldn't find the documentation on the feature to make required support a function, but I'm fairly sure it's supported...

```
var OrderSchema = new Schema(
{

    status: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      enum: refdata.orderStatus,
      default: refdata.orderStatus[0]
    },

    createDate: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    },
    customerInfo: {
      type: OrderCustomer,
      required: function (v){
        return this.status === 'INIT';
      }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your code worked when I tried it with Mongoose 4.5.10.

Comment: I tried upgrading to 4.6 but still no luck. The `this` reference still doesn't seem right. In the debugger it looks like some sort of global object - it says "global" and then has properties Array, ArrayBuffer, Boolean etc. etc. I don't think the issue relates to the construction of the object, it's simple, just `new Order(jsonRepresentation)` where Order is the model derived from the schema.  I've successfully used a function for required elsewhere in code too, could it have something to do with `customerInfo` being a schema definition?

Comment: interesting I just tried it on createDate, same function and the this reference is correct. Wonder if that's a bug....

Comment: Hmm...I didn't have your `OrderCustomer` object so I was using `String` instead. Maybe it only works with standard types. Anyway, try the approaches from here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760253/mongoose-custom-validation-using-2-fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve what you want using `pre` middleware.

For more information on `pre`, see [Mongoose middleware documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

use `pre` while `saving` and apply your `logic` to check if a particular field is required or not. Based on your logic implemented in `pre('save')`, If it is `required` or `not required`, you can flag an error in either case.

Try something like this:

```
var OrderSchema = new Schema(..);
OrderSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  // check if it is required or not
  if(this.status == "INIT")
  {
    //customerInfo Required
    //check if customerInfo is present or not.
    // Flag issue if not present.
    var err = new Error('customerInfo required');
    next(err);
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks I know I can use pre save middleware. But will be neater to use a function definition as I want to reuse the function on many other properties of the object once this one is working, and I'm also confident it should work with recent version of Mongoose....

Comment: marking this correct, maybe there's another way with the `checkRequired` on a custom schema type, but I couldn't figure it out. So ended up using `pre validate` and calling `this.invalidate` rather than pre-save because then at least the errors object is consistent with `ValidationError` rather than generic `Error`.